# Как сделать разрыв строк при выводе

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bs4

У меня есть такой код:

```
import traceback
import requests
import dateparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url): # <Остается
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html): # <  Собираем главнные новости.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})

# < Этот цикл отбирает только ссылки на главные новости.
    counter = 0
    links_rcv = []
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container.find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            links_rcv.append(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
            #print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1
    return links_rcv


def get_context_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'fullnews white_block'})  # < Получаем контекст.


    if mainblock is not None:  # < Если контекст не пуст, продолжаем разбор.
        item_title = mainblock.find('h1').text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p')
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:  # < Иначе получаем и разбираем контекст другого типа.
        mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
        item_title = soup.find('title').text
        item_datetime = soup.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    return (item_title,item_datetime,item_text)  # < Возвращаем результат, вне зависимости от типа страницы.


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    links_rcv = get_page_link(get_html(url))
    for i in links_rcv:
        try:
            print(get_context_data(get_context_html(i)))
        except:
            print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
            print(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

И при выводе он выводит данные не слишком корректно.

[image: Вот такая каша при выводе]

**UPD** хотелось бы видеть в таком формате:
**Заголовок  Дата  Текстовой контент**

**UPD1** При использовании кода такая ошибка(ответ ниже)
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/PycharmProjects/Task/zakonkz/parser V2 .py", line 63, in <module>
    for i in links_rcv:
NameError: name 'links_rcv' is not defined`

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при выводе он выводит данные не слишком корректно

Укажите в каком виде Вы хотите видеть данные.

```py
def get_context_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'fullnews white_block'})  # < Получаем контекст.
    text_content = ''


    if mainblock is not None:  # < Если контекст не пуст, продолжаем разбор.
        item_title = mainblock.find('h1').text
        item_datetime = mainblock.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p')
        for text in item_text:
            text_content += f'{text.text}\n'
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:  # < Иначе получаем и разбираем контекст другого типа.
        mainblock = soup.find('div',{'class':'full_story'})
        item_title = soup.find('title').text
        item_datetime = soup.find('div',{'class':'news_date'}).text
        item_text = mainblock.findAll('p',{'class':'MsoNormal'})
        for text in item_text:
            text_content += f'{text.text}\n'
        item_datetime=dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    return (item_title,item_datetime,text_content)  # < Возвращаем результат, вне зависимости от типа страницы.
```

Например можно выводить так:

```py
for i in links_rcv:
    for item in get_context_data(get_context_html(i)):
        try:
            print(item)
        except:
            print(f'Ошибка на странице: {i}')
            print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Тогда у Вас будет выведено:

В Гренландии зафиксировали катастрофическое таяние льда

2019-08-09 00:45:00

TEXT

Comment: Добавил в каком формате нужно

Comment: @r4khic обновил

Comment: код не работает.добавил upd @The Marshang

Comment: @r4khic обновил. С копи-пастом Вы далеко не уедете.

Comment: копипастом чего?

Comment: Вы задаете 3й вопрос, в содержимом которого уже содержатся ответы. Тот же вопрос с условием `if` - во время выполнения скрипта ошибка логируется. Прочитать ошибку и посмотреть почему - вот что надо было сделать.

Comment: Окей.В следующий раз учту.